# buttons resizing on site with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have been working on a site using the Download ready-to-use compiled code for Bootstrap v4.1.3 provided on the bootstrap page, and after reading how to work on the nav and the buttons I have stumbled into a problem.

below of my meta tags I have the css links

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="addons/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="addons/css/core-style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="addons/css/menustyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-info fixed-top">
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="/docs/4.1/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top">
         Bootstrap</a>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Facultad</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Alumnos</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Consultas<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="mx-auto"><b><h4>Consulta General [Notas]</h4></b></div>
          </div>
        </nav>
</header>
<section>...<section>
<section>...<section>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" style="width:auto" onClick="window.location.href='../Consultas.html'">Menu Consultas</button>
<section>...<section>
<footer>...</footer>
    <!-- Opptional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The only fix I have for the button that I have in the body bellow all the other code but on the nav the code `button` tag does the same for the code of `a` tag
[image]
[image]

From the navbar the only one that has given me a problem is Placeholder that is between the `a`tags same with the code below and that is when I hover over the button it gets smaller and that changes the height of the navbar when I hover it, link works fine and all is just that the hover, also the same happens when I use the code for the `button` on the Navbar provided by bootstrap

```
<a class="btn btn-secondary" href="Menu.php" role="button">Menu Principal</a>
```

the `button` on my code works but the `a` with role=button on another page does the same as the nav.
[image]
[image]

Don't know if I fully explained my issue or is easy to understand, also the code I been using is on the documentation of the Bootstrap site, also for the navbar if I don't put `fixed-top` on the class it leaves a white space at the top of the page I put the following code on menustyle.css but it didn't fix it, is there another way to remove the white space without the need to use `fixed-top` in the nav class?

```
header{
    margin:0px;
}
body{
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: If your examples above are actually how your page is structured, that would be a problem - your example has content outside of the html tag, which would mean your page is invalid. I'm assuming this is just a copy/paste error - can you edit this to be closer to your actual markup?

Comment: can you create a working demo for your problem

Comment: no the `header` is inside the body I didn't put everything since I have sections after the header to other things that the page works I just put it that way to show where the problem is and where I have the js and links to the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">nav-bar</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active" title="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Hey, this is the working snippet for nav bar . Please show us the issue which you're facing

Comment: Please try to add your actual issue that you're facing to the above code snippet.